# Spark streaming on Mesos - course grained

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, mesos, mesosphere

I have 2 cores on my vagrant development machine, and want to run 2 streaming applications.

If:

- both of them take both available cores ( I didn't specify "spark.cores.max")
- they have streaming interval of 15 seconds
- 5 seconds is enough to perform computation

Is expected behaviour of Mesos to shift these 2 available cores between 2 applications? I would expect that behaviour, because "Mesos locks the resources until job is executed", and in Spark Streaming one job is what is executed within batch interval.

Otherwise, If resources are locked for the life of application (in spark streaming it is forever), what is the benefit of using Mesos instead of Standalone cluster manager?

Answer (score 2):

Spark Streaming locks each stream `Reader` to a core, plus you'll need at least one other core for the rest of the processing. So you can't run two jobs simultaneously on a 2-core machine.

Mesos gives you much better resource utilization in a cluster. Standalone is more static. It might fine, though, for a fixed number of long-running streams, as long as you have enough resources and you use the recommendations for capping the allowed resources each job can grab (default is to grab everything).

If you're really just running on a single machine, use `local[*]` to avoid the overhead of master and slave daemons, etc.